# Hygiene tag proposal?

Tags: feature-request, tags

There is a `personal-hygiene` tag, for yourself, but I recently asked a question about other people and there was no `hygiene` tag.

Could we possibly get a hygiene tag?

Answer (score 7):

[personal-hygiene](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-hygiene) should work for anyone's hygiene, not just your own. If it relates to the hygiene of a person (as opposed to any other thing), then it's personal hygiene. If you look at the questions tagged with [personal-hygiene](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-hygiene), even excluding yours, there are several that relate to *other* people.

[How can I politely tell someone that they should take a shower?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-can-i-politely-tell-someone-that-they-should-take-a-shower)

[How to deal with someone accidentally spitting in my food while dining out](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/223/how-to-deal-with-someone-accidentally-spitting-in-my-food-while-dining-out)

So, I think the use is already what you wish it to be.

I see no need for a second tag at this point.

Comment: I agree. Examples of hygiene that are not personal hygiene: sterilizing surgical tools, cleaning your shower, or storing refrigerated food at the proper temperature.